# Magento 2 nested dynamic rows uicomponent

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent, dynamic-rows

I want to use nested dynamic rows components.

I have 3 sections.

1. **Items**
   'Add Item' button to add Item section.
2. **Ingredients (inside Item)**
   Each Item section can have one or more Ingredient sections with **'Add Ingredient'** button
3. **Directions (inside Item)**
   Each Item section can have one or more Direction sections with **'Add Direction'** button.

How can I achieve this functionality?

All sections are dynamic rows.

Comment: Did u achieve this?